# Funny French book about etymology and grammar

Tags: étymologie

Are there funny French books about the etymology of words, like "Word perfect" by Susie Dent for English etymology, or "have you eaten your grandma" by  Gyles Brandreth for English grammar?

Comment: Or "Eats, Shoots and Leaves"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

<sub><sub><sub><sup><sup><sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.</sup></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub>